# Using push inside of map still returns null array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting a list of processes and I'm trying to map through them and add certain properties to an object, which is then pushed into an array. When I console log it out its fine, but in gql client/front end im getting null results.

```
                    let results = []
                    await list.forEach((process) => {
                        results.push({
                            name: process.name,
                            created_at: process.pm2_env.created_at,
                            pm_uptime: process.pm2_env.pm_uptime,
                            status: process.pm2_env.status,
                            memory: process.monit.memory,
                            cpu: process.monit.cpu
                        })
                    })

                    const contents = await Promise.all(results);
                    console.log(contents);
```

I've also tried using `map`, `forEach` and `for/of`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `results` appears to be an array of plain objects. What is the purpose of `Promise.all(results)`?

Comment: You can't `await list.forEach` since `forEach` doesn't return anything

Comment: Do not use `.map()` if you just want to loop thru an array and push values to a different array that you already initialized `let results = []` if you are not going to use the array that `.map()` already creates for you. It is a bad practice

Comment: To make the above clear, if you remove `await` and change `await Promise.all(results);` to just `results`, then your code will work. Nothing about the loop is async, so implementing `await` here is just causing issues.

Comment: @Jaood_xD - That is _technically_ incorrect. You _can_ `await undefined`. It just doesn't have any use.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - You are correct that you can just remove those things, but `await Promise.all([1, 2, 3])` will just return `[1, 2, 3]` (via a very expensive route). If the OP is getting "_null results_" in "_gql client/front end_", then removing those `await` keywords probably will have no effect.

Comment: @JDB true - all that's needed to make it work is to remove the first `await`. But the latter has no purpose and needs to be removed too, although it's not causing any ill behaviour

Comment: @JDB You're right. My bad that I expressed the thought in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I had some odd behaviour with this one but solved it eventually.

I ended up throwing it into a function that returned a promise.

```
const getPm2List = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pm2.list(async (err, list) => {
          if (err) throw new GraphQLError('Unable to connect to PM2')

          resolve(list)
      })
  })
}

const processList = await getPm2List()

processList.forEach((process) => {
  results.push({
      name: process.name,
      pm_uptime: process.pm2_env.pm_uptime,
      status: process.pm2_env.status,
      memory: process.monit.memory,
      cpu: process.monit.cpu
  })
})

return results
```